# Display PDF file from C# to Angular2 view

Tags: c#, angular, pdf, itext

I'm trying to display a PDF that was previously uploaded into the server. The PDF resides inside the App_Data folder. I want to fetch it using C# Web API 2 and display it in my Angular 2 frontend view.

C# code:

```
  HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  string filename = "somefilename.pdf";
  byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
  MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();


  if (filename != "") {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath) + "/App_Data/Uploads/PDFs/" + filename);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memStream);

    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    buffer = memStream.ToArray();
    response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(buffer));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
    if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=" + filename, out contentDisposition))
    {
      response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
    }
  }

  return response;
```

Angular 2 code:

```
this.documentsService.getFile()
                .subscribe((response: any) => {
                    let file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    window.open(url);
                });
```

I think my Angular code is wrong. But nevertheless, my first goal here is to fetch it from the MVC side. Right now the file gets downloaded and it's corrupted or there's not fetch correctly. It always give me a 15bytes size PDF file, so I know there's something wrong. I'm using iTextSharp in my C# backend.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the length of the buffer, before returning the response?

Comment: Actually I don't know how that thing works, so I really don't know. Sorry.

Comment: Why not swap to using the File API and just opening the PDF file, and returning the binary stream? From there, see if you can open it just using your web browser. Be sure to get the MIME type right - I believe it's supposed to be application/pdf or application/octet.

Comment: @PSGuy can you show a sample code?

Comment: @Jed, see my answer. Works for me. Can't speak to Angular, but I know the controller code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comment (providing an answer is easier for code):

```
if (filename != "") {
    var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename);
    _myDisposable = fs; // see further down in this answer.
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(fs);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    return response;
}

return response;
```

**Edit**: The code I posted above works for me. The only problem is disposing of the stream. The best way to probably do that is by creating a private IDisposable member on your controller class, and then adding a dispose override, sort of like this:

```
private IDisposable _myDisposable;
public override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && _myDisposable != null)
        _myDisposable.Dispose();
}
```

Please note that this assumes ASP.NET is done with the request (which seems reasonable, because it's disposing of your controller), which should be correct.

Comment: Yes this worked for me. I can handle the Angular part. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accepting :) Please keep an eye on that disposable bit.. I always get a little bit nervous when I don't own the call to the Dispose method :p

Comment: I've updated this answer to show how you could handle disposal of the resource stream once it's open. Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Why not use the `using` statement on the stream `using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())`

Comment: A `using` statement is often a good idea, but for the example, I don't think it would actually work, because the response stream isn't necessarily written immediately in the controller action, it's written later on in the ASP.NET pipeline. This may not be true for this particular example, but it's definitely true when returning Entity Framework queries directly from the controller without calling the `.ToList()` extension method. So, my general recommendation is acquire the disposable, set it in the controller, and dispose at the end.